# Why do react hooks reference old data in event handlers?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using hooks to maintain state of an array containing data along with a button component. This component has an `onClick` event handler.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const initialData = [{ "field": "foo", "button": getButton("foo") }];
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(initialData);

  const getButton = (entry) => <Button onClick={() => doStuff(entry)}>Hello</Button>

  const doStuff = (entry) => console.log(data)

  const addData = () => {
    const moreData = { "field": "bar", "button": getButton("bar") }
    setData([ ...data, moreData ])

    const evenMoreData = { "field": "roll", "button": getButton("roll") }
    setData([ ...data, evenMoreData ])
  }

  const myList = data.map(d => <>{d.field} {d.button}</>)

  return (
    <>
      {myList}
      <Button onClick={() => doStuff('foo')}>Hi</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => addData()}>Add Data</Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

This `data` gets rendered correctly in `myList`. When I click the button in `foo`, it calls `doStuff` which prints `data` as an empty array (as if it was a snapshot in time before `foo` was added). If I click the button in `bar`, it prints an array with only `foo` in it. If I click the button in `roll`, it prints an array with only `foo` and `bar` in it.

However, If I add an identical button outside of `myList`, it can print `data` correctly containing all `foo`, `bar` and `roll`. Why is this so and how can I work around this?

My current workaround involves `useEffect` and introducing another hook to maintain state of which button was pressed, but this doesn't seem very elegant to me splitting logic away from where you expect it to be.

Comment: Please post more of you code - the full component if possible. From your description it is quite confusing what is going on - can you clarify it?

Comment: apologies. hope that my edit is clearer?

Comment: Why are those `setState` calls inside the function component's render body? That will not work. The render should be based on `props` and `current state` only. State changes should be done by event handlers, or effects inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: that's besides the point. i've edited it to sit inside setData now. the question remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see the behavior you state is because you are storing components within state and so when you actually render it, the reference of the function for the rendered component is when it was actually put into state

You can make a small change in your code to update the behavior. You just need to render the button while you are actually rendering the component and not when you update the state.

Also while adding more data, use state updater callback pattern

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const initialData = [{ "field": "foo"}];
  const [ data, setData ] = React.useState(initialData);

  const getButton = (entry) => <button onClick={() => doStuff(entry)}>Hello</button>

  const doStuff = (entry) => console.log(data)

  const addData = () => {
    const moreData = { "field": "bar" }
    setData(prev=> ([ ...prev, moreData ]))

    const evenMoreData = { "field": "roll"}
    setData(prev => ([ ...prev, evenMoreData ]))
  }

  const myList = data.map(d => <React.Fragment>{d.field} {getButton(d.field)}</React.Fragment>)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {myList}
      <button onClick={() => doStuff('foo')}>Hi</button>
      <button onClick={() => addData()}>Add Data</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: so here's the restriction: i don't get to control the actual render as the entire data object is passed as a prop into a third-party grid component. does this mean that the useEffect workaround i did is actually the only way to go?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not able to control the render, you must always store the data in state and not components.

Comment: it's a third-party component. I pass it data and it renders. except i want it to render a component instead of just text. assuming this third-party component does not have means for me to define a custom render, then I have no choice.

Comment: more often than not, you have atleast the children prop that you can use to render data. However, please let me know the component that you wish to use from a 3rd party library

Comment: it's an internal component that wraps react-table. i'll check with the team to see if they can allow more props to pass through to access the native react-table props.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn **Button** into a component and do something like that:

```js
const initialData = { field: "foo" };

function App() {
  
  const [data,setData] = React.useState(initialData);
  
  function toggleButton() {
    setData((prevState) => {
      return prevState.field === "foo" ?
        {field: "bar"}
      : {field: "foo"}
    });
  }
  
  
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        Current data.field: {data.field}
        <button onClick={toggleButton}>
            Toggle button
        </button>
      </div>
      <Button value={data.field}/>
    </div>
  );
}


function Button(props) {
  function doStuff() {
    console.log(props.value);
  }
  return(
    <button onClick={doStuff}>Do Stuff {props.value}</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: i think my original question might be unclear, but all i'm trying to do is build identical buttons in a list that have an event handler that can access this common data state managed by hooks. are you suggesting to pass an entire function as a prop instead?